# About the irreducibility in $k[X,Y]$ and in $k(Y)[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a generic field and $k(Y)$ be the field of rational function in the variable $Y$. If $f\in k[X,Y]$  is an irreducible polynomial,  is it true that it is irreducible as polynomial in $k(Y)[X]$?

Comment: If it's primitive then you can just use Gauss's lemma.

Comment: @YACP Of course, I was thinking about the case $R[x,y]$ where $R$ is a UFD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following equivalence (=some version of Gauss's lemma) answers your question:

> For a polynomial $f(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$ the following are equivalent:
>   (i) The polynomial $f(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$ is irreducible in the ring $k[X,Y]$ .
>   (ii) The polynomial  $f(X,Y)$, seen as a polynomial in the indeterminate $X$ with coefficients in $k[Y]$, is primitive **and**  the polynomial $f(X,Y)$ is irreducible in the ring $k(Y)[X]$.

Here "primitive" means that if you write $f(X,Y)=\sum a_i(Y)X^i$, no positive degree polynomial $g(Y)$ divides all the coefficients $a_i(Y)$ 's .

Comment: I have answered this (very classical) question because it is often answered in a roundabout way, while the equivalence above is a very efficient and easy to remember criterion.

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Glad it helped you, Galoisfan.